# How can I have vertical lines without borders in Grid

Tags: html, css

I am trying to draw vertical lines without borders.

I tried this code. But it draws horizontal lines in a box. Can someone please tell me how to do this.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .5;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements</h1>
<p>A Grid Layout must have a parent element with the <em>display</em>property set to <em>grid</em>or
    <em>inline-grid</em>.</p>
<p>Direct child element(s) of the grid container automatically becomes grid items.</p>
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that will answer exactly what you are looking for, but if you put border-right, border-left you have "vertical" lines

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .5;
}

.grid-item {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements</h1>
<p>A Grid Layout must have a parent element with the <em>display</em>property set to <em>grid</em>or <em>inline-grid</em>.</p>
<p>Direct child element(s) of the grid container automatically becomes grid items.</p>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```